# Variable inside variable gitlab ci

Tags: variables, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

Is there a way to use predefined variable inside custom variable in gitlab ci like this:

```
before_script:
  - cat "${$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}" >> .env
```

to extract the name of branch from `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` and use it as a name of custom variable

Update:

[image]

Comment: lets say `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=production`, would you like to have `${production}` in `.env` ?

Comment: exactly, and "production" is the name of custom variable declared in "CI/CD Settings -> Variables" in gitlab. Which values is what I want to have in .env. I have updated with screenshot.

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve it? .I have the same problem

Answer (score 14):

Check out [GitLab 14.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/09/22/gitlab-14-3-released/#use-variables-in-other-variables) (September 2021)

> ### Use variables in other variables
>
> CI/CD pipeline execution scenarios can depend on expanding variables declared in a pipeline or using GitLab predefined variables within another variable declaration.
>
> In 14.3, we are enabling the “**variables inside other variables**” feature on GitLab SaaS.
>
> **Now you can define a variable and use it in another variable definition within the same pipeline**.
>
> You can also use GitLab predefined variables inside of another variable declaration.
>
> This feature simplifies your pipeline definition and eliminates pipeline management issues caused by the duplicating of variable data.
>
> Note - for GitLab self-managed users the feature is disabled by default.
> To use this feature, your GitLab administrator will need to enable the [feature flag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#nested-variable-expansion).
>
> ([demo -- video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atURdXuQcXE))
>
> [image: demo]
>
> See [Documentation]https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/ee8cb300efb6f917eab6d865c9d430eb62077b44/doc/ci/variables/index.md#use-variables-in-other-variables) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1809).

Q4 2023: the documentation now refers to [Use CI/CD variables in other variables](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/08ff8fa22da664de3cf93c67009579a958ce7714/doc/ci/variables/index.md#use-cicd-variables-in-other-variables)

> ### Use CI/CD variables in other variables
>
> You can use variables inside other variables:
>
> ```yaml
> job:
>  variables:
>    FLAGS: '-al'
>    LS_CMD: 'ls "$FLAGS"'
>  script:
>    - 'eval "$LS_CMD"'  # Executes 'ls -al'
> ```
>
> Use the `$` character in CI/CD variables.
> If you do not want the `$` character interpreted as the start of another variable, use `$$` instead:
>
> ```yaml
> job:
>  variables:
>    FLAGS: '-al'
>    LS_CMD: 'ls "$FLAGS" $$TMP_DIR'
>  script:
>    - 'eval "$LS_CMD"'  # Executes 'ls -al $TMP_DIR'
> ```
>
> ### Prevent CI/CD variable expansion
>
> Introduced in GitLab 15.7.
>
> Expanded variables treat values with the `$` character as a reference to another variable.
> CI/CD variables are expanded by default. To treat variables with a $ character as raw strings, disable variable expansion for the variable

---

[`dba`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3733247/dba) asks in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67005507/variable-inside-variable-gitlab-ci/69339253?noredirect=1#comment128415850_69339253):

> Does this include or exclude using globally defined variables?

dba's own answer:

> Global variables *can* be reused, but they need the `local_var: ${global_var}` syntax with recursive expansion (independent of the shell).

Comment: should be pined as correct answer!

Comment: Does this include or exclude using globally defined variables?

Comment: @dba I don't know for sure, as I haven't tested it directly. Do you have a pipeline to test it out on gitlab.com (15.0+) or on a private instance (14.3 at least)?

Comment: I'm struggling with it on a private instance 14.9, but that may be because I'm using the pwsh runner which has the ambiguity between $var (gitlab variable syntax) and $Env:var (powershell variable syntax)

Comment: @dba OK, that could be a good question on its own, to illustrate that issue.

Comment: I think I got it. Global variables _can_ be reused, but they need the `local_var: ${global_var}` syntax with recursive expansion (independent of the shell). The  examples in the docs suggest something else unfortunately.

Comment: @dba Thank you for this interesting feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Is this still a supported feature? The link to documentation seems to point to a header that no longer exists, and I'm struggling to find references to "variable in variable" or the like elsewhere in the docs. Just spent an hour debugging why my pipeline wasn't running, and using this pattern seemed to be the culprit (though it could have very well been developer error on my part).

Comment: @EliasBenevedes Yes it is. I have restored the original link for the "Documentation", but also included a reference to the current (Q4 2023) documentation in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check if this matches [`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 1809](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1809):

> ### Description
>
> - In the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, a user can define a variable and use it in another variable definition within the same `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.
> - A user can also use a GitLab pre-defined variable in a variable declaration.
>
> ### Example
>
> ```yaml
> variables:
>   variable_1: "foo"           # here, variable_1 is assigned the value foo
>   variable_2: "${variable_1}" # variable_2 is assigned the value variable_1. 
>   #  The expectation is that the value in variable_2 = value set for variable_1
> ```

If it is, it should be completed/implemented for GitLab 14.1 (July 2021)

Answer (score 1):

Lots of options.

### But you could just pass the predefined var into the `.env`

```yaml
image: busybox:latest

variables:
  MY_CUSTOM_VARIABLE: $CI_JOB_STAGE
  ANIMAL_TESTING: "cats"

before_script:
  - echo "Before script section"
  - echo $CI_JOB_STAGE
  - echo $MY_CUSTOM_VARIABLE
  - echo $MY_CUSTOM_VARIABLE >> .env
  - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH >> .env
  - cat .env
```

#### example [pipeline output](https://gitlab.com/codeangler/make-ci-var-custom-var-in-script/-/jobs/1163552875)

```sh
$ echo "Before script section"
Before script section
$ echo $CI_JOB_STAGE
build
$ echo $MY_CUSTOM_VARIABLE
build
$ echo $MY_CUSTOM_VARIABLE >> .env
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH >> .env
$ cat .env
build
exper/ci-var-into-env
$ echo "Do your build here"
Do your build here
```

### or  pass it in earlier.

```yaml
image: busybox:latest

variables:
  MY_CUSTOM_VARIABLE: "${CI_JOB_STAGE}"
  ANIMAL_TESTING: "cats"

before_script:
  - echo "Before script section"
  - echo $CI_JOB_STAGE
  - echo $MY_CUSTOM_VARIABLE
  - echo $MY_CUSTOM_VARIABLE >> .env
  - cat .env
```

example: https://gitlab.com/codeangler/make-ci-var-custom-var-in-script/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Thanks, but you got me little wrong. By custom variable I meant the one, that is located in gitlab ci/cd settings - > variables. I have attached the screenshot in my post.

Comment: It does seem I do not understand your desired outcome.  @wspven maybe describe what you are trying to achieve and not how you think you should achieve it?  In the mean time the CI variable precedence  maybe helpful   https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#cicd-variable-precedence